# How to fill the space of image which visibility is made gone

Tags: android, listview, imageview, visibility

i'm having a list view with image,textview and 2 buttons at the right side.when i set the visibility of second button to gone the first image is moved to left and it overlaps on the imageview.but i want that button to fill the area of the gone button.how to achieve this,please let me know..
my xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="#ffffff">
<ImageView 
android:src="@drawable/icon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/messageimageview"/>
<TextView 
android:text="Some text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:id="@+id/messagetext"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messageimageview"/>
<Button 
android:id="@+id/type2btn"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:background="@drawable/delete"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/messagetext"/>
<Button 
android:visibility="invisible"
android:id="@+id/type1btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/apply"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/type2btn"
android:layout_below="@+id/messagetext"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Would be neat to have your xml for the list item. Perhaps set the visibility to invisible? Otherwise, insert code to your question.

Comment: i got the solution for my own problem..i just used image that will overlap on the second image and working with visibility i removed the space..that's it....

Answer (score 0):

```
Use setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); instead of setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: i want that space to be filled